# wrapping figure in line with text on latex

Tags: floats, wrapfigure, front-matter

I want to add logo picture in line with text as shown in figure [image: logo](it is the picture of word document)  for that purpose my code is given below

```
\begin{center}\Large { \textbf{University name\\ }}\end{center}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.5\textwidth}
     \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{logo.png}
    \end{wrapfigure}

\begin{center} { address and url }\end{center}


\begin{center}\LARGE {\underline{\textbf{Certificate of  Approval}}}\end{center}

 \begin{center}
    \Large {\bf thesistitle }
 \vspace*{1.0cm}

\normalsize
By \\

\vspace*{15pt}


{\bf name}\\
 \end{center}      


\normalsize
```

but i seems to be some problem it give picture on the bottom of page.
How can i put my logo picture on the left side of University name?
Please Help me......

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a full, compilable code, with the preamble you use?

Comment: your code fragment can not be run but surely you get warnings from lines such as `By \\ ` don't you? I would expect it to make lines with maximum (10000) badness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do something like the following. I simplified you code  and, as your logo doesn't have to float, replaced the `wrapfigure` environment with `\InsertBoxL` command from the plain TeX macro package `insbox`. This command takes as a first argument the number of unshortened lines before the contents of the box is inserted.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\input{insbox.tex}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\InsertBoxL{1}{\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{hare-blazon.png}}
\begin{center}\Large \textbf{University name}\\
address and url

\vspace{15ex}
\LARGE \bfseries \underline{Certificate of Approval}

 thesistitle

\normalsize\mdseries
\vspace*{4ex}
by
\vspace*{4ex}

{\bfseries name}
\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not work. Give error message `Undefined control sequence. \InsertBoxL`

Comment: Do you have `insbox` installed?

Comment: No, How can I install `insbox` ? Is `insbox` is a package name?  I write the code `\usepackage{insbox}` but it give error message `insbox.sty  not found`

Comment: Look at my code: it's a `plain TeX` macro package. You have to load it with `\input{insbox.tex}`. If it's not nstalled, do it through your package manager (`tlmgr` for TeX Live, `TeX Live Utility` for MacTeX, `MiKTeX Package Manager` for…, well, MiKTeX.

Comment: Please tell me a easy way to do this. I cannot understand what you saying

Comment: What is your distribution?